# Change apk icon in android

Tags: android, android-install-apk

Maybe this question has a very easy solution but I don't have found any helpful information about this problem on internet.

I have correctly changed the application icon of my Android App but when I deploy the apk on my tablet I have noticed that it has still the old icon.

The apk is the debug version compiled with Android 1.1.0.

Anyone have any idea about this problem?

Thanks at all in advance.

Comment: Try to uninstall the application if any installed previously with the same package on your phone.

Comment: Hi @cafebabe1991. I have already installed and uninstalled the previous App. However my problem isn't on App installed that displays the icon correctly but on the apk debug compiled with Android 1.1.0 that still displays an old icon.

Comment: Yes I know...just to be clear I said that because having the same package sometimes does such problems.. So I said to verify..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have changed your icon only inside the `/drawable` folder, but you have icons defined for other densities, that are used in your tablet, look into the folders:

- `/drawable-mdpi`
- `/drawable-hdpi`
- `/drawable-xhdpi`
- `/drawable-xxhdpi`

and change the old version of your icon there.

[image]

Comment: Hi @elenasys. Thanks for the reply. I have already inserted the icon in these folders. Precisely in drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi and drawable-mdpi.
Also in the file AndroidManifest.xml I have already inserted the code `android:icon="@drawable/icon"` and I can see the correct icon.